# Log file for ReportServerTempDB growing unexpectedly

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

The transaction log file for the ReportServerTempDB database (database installed with Reporting Services) is has grown to over 100GB. And I'm not sure why.

Here are the file sizes:

- D:\SQLDatabases\ReportServer.mdf - 0.7GB
- G:\SQLDatabases\ReportServer.ldf - 1.8GB
- E:\SQLDatabases\ReportServerTempDB.mdf - 5GB
- G:\SQLDatabases\ReportServerTempDB.ldf - **107.6GB**

Recovery mode for all these database is **SIMPLE**.
We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.

EDIT: Something that is unique to the reporting services databases: 
The collation for these databases is Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS. But for all other database it is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

I don't want to just shink the log files and carry on, because they might just grow again. And I can't see why they should be so large.

1. Does anyone know what could cause the log file (and the data file) for the ReportServerTempDB database to grow so much
2. And what I should do about it?
3. Could this indicate a problem with our Report Server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We had renamed SSRS, but the cleanup / archive procs were still trying to cleanup the old database names. When we changed that, out problem stopped.

Comment: Can you tell how exactly you did it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that your temp DB is on `recovery model - simple` as well?

At least you can shrink the database so you get your disk space back using `SHRINK DBCC`, check this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms190488.aspx

Comment: Both ReportServer & ReportServerTempDB are SIMPLE recovery mode. I have the space. I am more concerned about know why this has happened and what it means.

Comment: You users uses subscriptions? If so they create reports time based and store them all without removing older ones? That can cause the grow of the database.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just queried the Subscriptions table and no subscriptions -- but good to know.

Comment: In the database there are also auto-grow and shrink options.Is it possible that you auto grow but not shrink?